# smartd: not receive test email

Tags: linux, arm, monitoring, operation

I try to use smartmontools to monitor my device and I met 2 problems:

1. can't receive the test email

As the document says:http://smartmontools.sourceforge.net/man/smartd.conf.5.html, I configure the conf file with:

```
/dev/sda -m my@exaple.com -M test
```

and I start the smartd with:

```
/etc/init.d/smartd start
```

However, I don't receive the test email. I've no idea how to solve it.

BTW, As the device is something like a NAS, I guess may be there is no email service. But I don't know how to fix it.

2 log for the smartd is missing

I searched `/var/log`, and found nothing. Then I do the following:

- add `local3.*    /var/log/smartd3.log` to the file `/etc/syslog.conf`
- exec: `smartd -l local3`
- kill the smartd and start it again with: `/etc/init.d/smartd start`

Then,I still can't find the log file. why it is missing?

My smartmontool is 5.38 [arm-unknown-linux-gnu].

Thanks!

Comment: anything in your mail server's logs? e.g. var/log/maillog?

Comment: result of /var/log: diskmonitor.log  lighttpd         upnpd.log        wtmp. There is no maillog. How can I set the mail service?

Comment: you'd need to have something like postfix, qmail, sendmail, etc... install to actually deliver email outside of your system.

Comment: thanks. how about the 2nd question: where is the location of smartd's log file?